# How to hide particular point shapes from LightningChart JS?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I would like to hide certain data points on click event of my grid. How can I achieve this  ? 
I have series with circle, triangle and square shape and would like to hide series using separate grid showing these symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dispose and restore series as long as you have reference to them.

```js
// Use PointSeries with Triangle shaped points as example and cache it.
const triangleSeries = chart.addPointSeries( { pointShape: PointShape.Triangle } )

// Add a checkbox to the chart for this example
const button = chart.addUIElement( UIElementBuilders.CheckBox )
// Set up the checkbox
button.setText('Click to hide/show series')
  .setPosition( {x: 95, y: 95 } )
  // Define the behavior when the button is clicked (changing its state)
  .onSwitch( (_, state) => {
    // The checkbox is in 'on' state, so restore series.
    if (state)
      // Restore the series to the chart, so it'll show in the chart again.
      triangleSeries.restore()
    else
      // Dispose the series from the chart, effectively 'hiding' it.
      triangleSeries.dispose()
})
```

You can modify the checkbox shapes using the `setPictureOff` or `setPictureOn` methods of the UIElementBuilder:

```js
// Create a checkbox
const checkBox = chart.addUIElement( UIElementBuilders.CheckBox
  // Modify the shape of the checkbox
  .setPictureOff(UIButtonPictures.Rectangle)
  .setPictureOn(UIButtonPictures.Rectangle)
)
```